# How to avoid same functionality get repeating and make it generic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to refactor below snippets as same functionality repeating more than 1 time.

Could someone tell me how to make it generic?

Since its duplication, I couldn't get code coverage.

```
method_a {
let category = [];
category.forEach(d => {
    if(d.includes("prop1","prop2")) {
        // something...
        this.otherMethod('string1');
    }
    if(d === "prop3") {
        this.otherMethod('string2');
    }
});
}


method_b {
// api response
data[0].category.forEach(d => {
    if(d.includes("prop1","prop2")) {
        this.otherMethod('string1');
    }
    if(d === "prop3") {
        this.otherMethod('string2');
    }
});
}
```

Here what is the confusion is `method_a` has a local variable as an empty array and `method_b` has value from JSON response.

Comment: Since `method_a` only appears to forEach over an _empty_ array, which means it will effectively do _nothing_, you can simply remove it :-)

Comment: `since its duplication i couldn't get code coverage` has nothing to do with not getting coverage. The callback of the `forEach` in `method_a` will never be called, because `category` is always empty, and as of that there will be no coverage for that portion of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is to do with avoiding repeated code:

The easiest way would be to store the duplicated functionality in it's own function.

```
handleCategory(d) {
    if(d.includes("prop1","prop2")) {
        // something...
        this.otherMethod('string1');
    }
    if(d === "prop3") {
        this.otherMethod('string2');
    }
}

method_a {
    let category = [];
    category.forEach(d => this.handleCategory(d));
}


method_b {
    // api response
    data[0].category.forEach(d => this.handleCategory(d));
}
```

Comment: Hi @TPHughes as per your above answer. i've tried same solution to similar issue. could you pls tell me whether im going correct or not?  existing code `this.commonService.custList.subscribe(resp =>{
    if(resp){
      this.category = "";
      this.patFlag = false;
    }
  });


  this.commonService.itemsList.subscribe(resp =>{
    if(resp){
      this.category = "";
      this.patFlag = false;
    }
  });`

Comment: refactored code `someFunc() {
    this.category = "";
    this.patFlag = false;
  }


  this.commonService.custList.subscribe(resp =>{
    if(resp){
      this.someFunc();
    }
  });


  this.commonService.itemsList.subscribe(resp =>{
    if(resp){
        this.someFunc();
    }
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Well if what the `forEach` method has to do is exactly the same in both cases, you could create a separate method for it.

```
category.forEach(loopAction);
data[0].category.forEach(loopAction);

function loopAction(d) {
    if(d.includes("prop1","prop2")) {
        this.otherMethod('string1');
    }
    if(d === "prop3") {
        this.otherMethod('string2');
    }
}
```